# JPanel Won't load images?

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing, jpanel

I'm trying to create an Image output from local folder on a JPanel(inside the JFrame) using these code, but the JFrame shows nothing:

```
package photo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public UI() {
        initComponents();
   }
public class ImagePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
         image = ImageIO.read(new File("D://Programming/Image Processing/Colour Temperature/Vampire-full.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);      
    }

}


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel Image;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I don't know whether I used the right semantic, please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Your panel isn’t added to anything (ie the frame)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Implementation code example please?

Comment: `add(new ImagePanel()` ... no offence, but this is basic 101 stuff which you should have mastered before attempting something as advanced as custom painting ... ps- You might find it simpler to just use a `JLabel` if you doing nothing more then displaying an image

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm a student and I'm bad at programming Language. Thanks for the help!

ps: I'm planning to build a Photo Editor

Comment: Then I would highly recommend you take some time to learn the basic how how the API works, it will save you lot of headaches in the future ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Noted!

Answer (score 0):

As @MadProgrammer said in the comments, you should add your panel to the frame. You would also need to set up the size of your JFrame if you want to see something when you launch your application.

For example change your UI constructor to something like:

```
public UI() {
   // set up the size of your frame
   this.setSize(800, 600);
   // set up a layout manager
   this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   initComponents();
}
```

You can use whatever values you want for the width and height of your frame. You should also set up the type of Layout manager you want to use (an instance of BorderLayout for example)

Then use your `initComponents()`method to add the panel

```
private void initComponents() {
   this.add(new ImagePanel());
}
```

With these changes your frame will display the image loaded in your ImagePanel

Comment: I manually set the size of my Frame and Panel by Dragging it. I wanted to use the "Image" Jpanel instead the "ImagePanel" JPanel because, I've set The "Image" position and Size by mouse.

Comment: OK, then all you need to do is to update your initComponents method to add a new instance of the ImagePanel like in the example that I provided, it should work.